# bytesio type abnormal Two pictures saved in the same way are of different types ： <class '_io.BytesIO'> and <class 'bytes'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, python-imaging-library, playwright

I found a strange thing. When I successively saved the pictures into bytesio (), their **types were completely different**. This makes the image processing behind me impossible (for some special reasons, **I can't save the image as root / a.png and so on**).

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import time
from io import BytesIO 

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser =await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = await browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors = True)
        page = await context.new_page()
        
        await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/")

        screen_first = BytesIO()
        screen_second = BytesIO()

        time.sleep(1)
        screen_first.write(await page.screenshot(full_page=True, type="png"))

        await page.fill(f'input >> nth=0','test')

        time.sleep(1)
        screen_second = await page.screenshot(full_page=True, type="png")

        print(id(screen_first))  #1594966975968    
        print(type(screen_first)) #<class '_io.BytesIO'>
        #print(screen_first)
        
        print(id(screen_second)) #1594944534144
        print(type(screen_second)) #<class 'bytes'> 
        #print(screen_second)
        time.sleep(5)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried the Google solution, but they all asked for the specific file path. I searched for IO keywords in stack overflow and found no similar problems. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saved in the same way, but in the second case you are overwriting the variable with return value of `.screenshot` method, which seems to be of the type `bytes`